# I am not able to run this simple code in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=SWITCH(Sept!B:B, jhalford, "No","YES")
```

this does not run at all

```
=SWITCH(Sept!B:B, jhalford, "No","YES")
```

I need to find the text `jhalford` and if it's in there then no else yes, but my result is all no.

Comment: So the string "jhalford" or the variable named `jhalford`? You have "No" and "YES" in double-quotes; you probably want `"jhalford"` in your function.

Comment: jhalford is the text in the sheet. i want to use google api to write a query to find the cells which contains jhalford word in it. if it has jhalford then "No" else "yes". apparently google apis use switch for any case statements.

Comment: I haven't messed with Google Sheets, but I know a lot about Excel functions; you probably need to use double quotes around the text to search for too: `=SWITCH(Sept!B:B, "jhalford", "No","YES")` -- try that.

Comment: i tried that too! didnt worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the reference to the entire column, then the SWITCH command has to be on row #1.

row 1 of column C should have

```
=SWITCH(Sept!B:B, "jhalford", "NO", "YES")
```

Otherwise, it messes up the reference point.